# Why isnt open mp parallelizing this code?

Tags: c, openmp

This code is not making the code calculating the 4 sums faster. Instead, it even takes more time. 
Also The output is not as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    int sum = 0,sum1 = 0,sum2 = 0,sum3 = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("%d",omp_get_thread_num());
                for(i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) sum = sum + 1;
            }
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("%d",omp_get_thread_num());
                for(i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) sum1 = sum1 + 1;
            }
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("%d",omp_get_thread_num());
                for(i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) sum2 = sum2 + 1;
            }
            #pragma omp section
            {
                printf("%d",omp_get_thread_num());
                for(i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) sum3 = sum3 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sum is %d %d %d %d",    sum,sum1,sum2,sum3);
}
```

The output is `sum is 218748707 222052401 239009041 196849489`

Do let me know the flaw in using openmp here.

Comment: What CPU, core framework are you running this on?

Comment: @kingchris I M RUNNING THIS ON INTEL CORE i3 processor

Comment: @kingchris when i use the command omp_get_num_procs, the output is 4..so can i use this processor to use openmp?

Comment: How are you timing the execution of the program ?

Comment: Timing the execution? Its simply evident that this code takes around 10 secs while the same sequential version takes around 6 secs.

Answer (score 5):

The slowdown stems from the fact that `sum`, `sum1`, `sum2` and `sum3` are shared variables and as such the compiler must generate fetch / update / store instructions for each increment instead of just keeping intermediate sum in a register as is the case for the serial version.

You should make each sum local to the thread it is used in. The easiest way to do it is to make a reduction over each sum:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i) reduction(+:sum,sum1,sum2,sum3)
{
    // Rest of the code goes unchanged
}
```

`private(i)` will solve the problem with incorrect results. `reduction(+:sum,sum1,sum2,sum3)` will make each thread accumulate its own copy of `sum`, `sum1`, `sum2` and `sum3`, and in the end local copies will be added up to form the final values.

Here are some performance figures:

Serial version - 3.812 seconds:

```
$ gcc -o mp.x mp.c -lgomp
$ time ./mp.x
0000sum is 500000000 500000000 500000000 500000000
./mp.x  3.81s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.812 total
```

OpenMP version with shared variables - 7.982 seconds:

```
$ gcc -fopenmp -o mp.x mp.c
$ time OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./mp.x
0132sum is 500000000 500000000 500000000 500000000
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./mp.x  21.88s user 0.86s system 284% cpu 7.982 total
```

OpenMP version with reduction - 1.226 seconds:

```
$ gcc -fopenmp -o mp.x mp.c
$ time OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./mp.x
0321sum is 500000000 500000000 500000000 500000000
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./mp.x  4.53s user 0.00s system 370% cpu 1.226 total
```

There is also another code transformation that additionally slows things down and it is the fact that `sum`, `sum1`, `sum2` and `sum3` are located on the stack of the main program while the sections code is being extracted by the OpenMP processor and put into separate function that is then called by each thread in the parallel team. This function is provided a data structure that contains pointers to the four shared sums and the code operates with those pointers. You can compare the assembler output in both cases and see for yourself - it is very instructive to do so if you'd like to dive deeper into parallel performance stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always free to use concurrency. There may be overhead involved that you don't see, for example creating new threads, locking memory areas and such. You can't always expect a performance boost for trivial tasks.

The reason you don't get the expected output is because all threads uses the same loop variable (`i`). This causes data races, which is also the reason your sums don't add up to 500000000.

Comment: even on using different loop variables, i get the correct result but the time taken is almost thrice the original sequential version. Whats the problem now?

Comment: @AakashAnuj There might be [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) going on between the `sum` variables since they are probably right next to each other on the stack.